# Increasing supply rails for low size MOSFETs

Tags: analog, cmos, nmos, scaling

With decreasing sizes of MOSFETs, the supply voltage has also scaled down so as that the electric fields in the device are not large enough for them to breakdown. However if this depends only on relative voltages, can we not increase the bulk voltage so that the supply voltage can also increase?

Specifically what I'm asking is that if I can stack one NMOS above another, the bottom one has its bulk grounded and its drain voltage does not exceed the nominal supply voltage given in the datasheet of 1.2V. The top NMOS however can have its bulk connected to say 0.6V and its drain can be connected to 1.8V. So the electric field across no device will exceed the breakdown voltage

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, my question is that if I increase all voltages (bulk, drain, source and gate) then can the absolute drain voltage exceed 1.2V. The relative potential differences between any two junctions would the same as in a normal design
This could potentially be a problem because the substrate is grounded and I might end up breaking down some junction with it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115979/discussion-on-question-by-aditya-sundar-increasing-supply-rails-for-low-size-mos).